# Saving a basic relation in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, relation

The example was straight forward but not surprisingly, it is not working. mLate is an object or array of objects from the Late table. 
My code:

```
var user = Parse.Object.extend("User"); 
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);        
var Late = Parse.Object.extend("Late");        
var lateQuery = new Parse.Query(Late);
userQuery.get("yCDDEWoiwM", {//this is where the userID goes
     success: function (userDetails) {
           var relation = userDetails.relation("mLate");
           relation.add(mLate);
           userDetails.save();
```

Given the Parse SDK, I can't imagine where I'm going wrong. I keep getting 
POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/yCDDEWoiwM 400 (Bad Request)

---

A NEW HYPOTHESIS AND MORE CODE

I know this is something really simple and I'm really pissed that Parse so rarely adds even slight detail to what they explain. Have you seen their API (OK, I don't want to get on my soap box . . .)

My hypothesis is that I transformed the Parse.Object from the Late table several times and that somehow Parse no longer knows what's going on there.

Here's a more complete look at the code:

```
var user = Parse.Object.extend("User"); 
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);        
    var Late = Parse.Object.extend("Late");        
    var lateQuery = new Parse.Query(Late);
    userQuery.get("yCDDEWoiwM", {//this is where the userID goes
         success: function (userDetails) {
mLate = [];
mLate1 = [];

lateQuery.find({
     success: function (allLate) {
          var aLate = allLate
          for (var i = 0; i < aLate.length; i++){
          var oneLate = aLate[i];
          if(something valid) {
          mLate.push(oneLate)
          }else{
          mLate1.push(oneLate)

var relation = userDetails.relation("mLate");
               relation.add(mLate);
               userDetails.save();
```

Comment: When I console.log(relation), mLate is undefined but when I console.log it outside the relation it is an array of objects very clean. What's going on there? I think that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extend the user that way.  All special classes (User, Installation, Roles, etc) should be addressed like this:

```
"_User", "_Roles", "_Installation"
```

so for example:

```
var user = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
```

But it's better to reference them in this way:

```
var user = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User);
```

But as far as I can tell you also don't need the first line creating a `user` object.  You also don't need to "extend" an object if all you wanted to do is created a query.  Typically "extending" is used if you want to create a pointer but in your case you don't need to.

See if this works for you:

```
//var user = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User); 
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);        
//var Late = Parse.Object.extend("Late");        
var lateQuery = new Parse.Query("Late");
userQuery.get("yCDDEWoiwM", {//this is where the userID goes
     success: function (userDetails) {
           var relation = userDetails.relation("mLate");
           relation.add(mLate);
           userDetails.save();
```

If you want to make the query a bit more dynamic you could do this:

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);               
queryQuery.equalTo("objectId", userId); 
userQuery.first().then(function(userDetails){

   var relation = userDetails.relation("mLate");
   relation.add(mLate);

   return Parse.Promise.when(userDetails.save());
}).then( // make your call to response.success ...);
```

Another possible issue is that your function is returning before your `userDetails.save()` operation has a chance to finish.  If you modify your query to be something like the above to use a [Promise](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Promise.html) then it will guarantee that the async call to `save()` will actually complete.

What is not shown is the continuation of the promise chain to call `response.success` or `error` but you can add that in.

Comment: Just to be clear are your suggestions for the Javascript SDK?  You may be right but so far I've found the pattern I showed above to hold true.  I"m pretty sure you could extend with .extend(Parse.User) also but I'm not aware of "_User", "_Roles", or "_Installation".  At the end of the day I want to properly model a vast number of many to many relationships so I really need a relation and have yet to get this code to save.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the Javascript SDK.  Here is an example straight from the documents about querying.  I think if you are seeing patterns of people to query for the user class with `Query("User")` it will never work however `Query("_User")` may work but the Parse teams advises against it. The documented way and the considered "correct" way is `Query(Parse.User)` https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-querying

Comment: Are you sure that that objectId still exists?  Maybe you deleted the object and a new one is in its place?

Comment: I edited my answer.  I think your issue may be that your either your `objectId` no longer exists or that your call to `userDetails.save()` doesn't have enough time to finish before your function returns (because it's async).

Comment: With your modifications to the code you still aren't giving your function long enough to complete the `.save()` operation. As I pointed out in my answer you need to call `Parse.Promise.when(userDetails.save());`. Since `save()` is asynchronous you need to let your function know that it needs to wait for the operation to complete and you do that by creating a Promise. All of your previous attempts may have been working but the function returns before `save()` can complete - especially if there are a lot of relations to add.  If you add this Promise your code should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Max. I appreciate your time/insight in helping me with this but I still haven't figured it out. When I try the promise save you suggest above, it tells me that my function is undefined. I know that's not true from console.log and the fact that it fills an array (mLate) which has objects in it when it finishes.  I think that could  be a problem.  I'm also wondering how the relation knows to which class/table the objects in the mLate array belong.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I just used var user = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User); and the response was that the first argument needs to be the class name. When I switched it to "User", it worked just find. Might this be an issue with relational mapping? Why is there no documentation for that that I can find? After lots of digging I just found one post that refers to it: https://www.parse.com/questions/javascript-sdk-adding-relational-data

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on the intent because the mLate variable is not defined, but you can get a user like this:

```
var user = new Parse.User({id:"yCDDEWoiwM"});
user.fetch().then(function(user) {
    // add to the relation here, then
    return user.save();
}).then(function () {
    console.log("saved");
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

I went with what you suggested: 

var user = new Parse.User("yCDDEWoiwM");
user.fetch().then(function(user){
var relation = user.relation("mLate");
relation.add(mLate);
return user.save();
})

Where am I going wrong? To be clear, mLate is a couple of objects out of the Late table. Each user may have many Late objects and any Late object may have many users.

Comment: The only difference there was the {id: }? I tried this and still received 400 Bad Request