# Parse Relation - Add the Missing Details for Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've been trying desperately to create a Parse relation with the Javascript SDK but I've found the documentation lacking.  Missing parts include, how does the relation know which two classes (tables) are being connected? What is the connection between using Parse.Relation and obj.relation?  Having seen a few example of variations on how to get Parse.Relation to work, I'm not even sure what to ask.  I do know that my previous question: [Saving a basic relation in Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900094/saving-a-basic-relation-in-parse/28902759?noredirect=1#comment46089530_28902759)

Has not been answered so maybe getting some detail on the documentation is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Where does it know which classes are being connected?**
It knows this by a) the class you create the column in and b) when you create the relation column, you define the target class.

[image: Adding a Relation on Parse.com]

**What is the connection between using Parse.Relation and obj.relation?**
`Parse.Relation` is just the classname of the relation itself and is nothing you should need to worry about. To get a relation for an object you call `obj.relation("columnName")`, store that in a variable, add/remove objects to/from it and save the object afterwards by calling `obj.save`.

The [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-pointers) (see Many-to-Many relationship) as a simple example for adding an object to the relation.

Comment: I've seen all of the documentation pertaining to relation.  Are you suggesting that you must create a relation in the Parse UI first before doing object calls in code? If so, please show me where this is suggested in the documentation.

Comment: If Client-Side class creation is enabled it should also work without adding the column in the databrowser before using it. The column might get auto-created when you save the first object. The class-determination should still be true, the requests the classname of an object in the relations array so it would create a proper connection.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean "Client-Side" class creation enabled"